# ES6 D3 formatting

Tags: javascript

I have some data that is mapped to this form.

```
[
    {source: 'Node A', target: 'Node B', value: 1},
    {source: 'Node A', target: 'Node B', value: 1}
]
```

I have been experimenting with JS again mainly due to the recent additions in ES6.  I'm trying to get the below form without resorting to loops.

```
{
    nodes: [
        {name: 'Node A'},
        {name: 'Node B'},
   ],

   links: [
        {source: 'Node A', target: 'Node B', value: 2}
   ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Well as you are dealing with multiple objects you are going to need to use a loop in one form or another.

Comment: Where is the *'value': 2* coming from?

Comment: It's the sum of the duplicate values in the above code.  I want to sum value for all matching source and target.  

As for loops, I'm referring to a map/reduce/filter solution, which of course depends on loops.

Comment: Can you please show us how you would write the code in ES5, or with loops? Then we can help you introducing more modern features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enjoy the magic:

```js
var data=[
    {source: 'Node A', target: 'Node B', value: 1},
    {source: 'Node A', target: 'Node B', value: 1}
];

function magic(arrOfObj) {
  var temp=arrOfObj.reduce((acc,cv)=>{
    if(!acc.nodes.includes(cv.source)) acc.nodes.push(cv.source);
    if(!acc.nodes.includes(cv.target)) acc.nodes.push(cv.target);
    if(!acc.links[cv.source+","+cv.target]) acc.links[cv.source+","+cv.target]=0;
    acc.links[cv.source+","+cv.target]+=cv.value;
    return acc;
  },{nodes:[],links:{}});
  temp.links=Object.entries(temp.links).map(entry=>{
    entryArr=entry[0].split(",");
    return ({source:entryArr[0], target:entryArr[1], value:entry[1]});
  });
  temp.nodes=temp.nodes.map(item=>({name:item}));
  return temp;
};

console.log(magic(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Very nice.  Your links section seems incorrect though, I'll have a look and see if it's a typo.

Comment: Thank you!
Fixed - copy-paste pitfalls... :)

Comment: Small typo:
    return ({source:entryArr[0], target:entryArr[0], value:entry[1]}); // <- enrtyArr[1]

Thanks!

Comment: Get 2 more reputation points and you can up-vote! :)